# From to Rotation Glitching My Character Controller

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, quaternions

So I am making a character controller which uses Quaternion.FromToRotation to align  the player with the gravity center in this piece of code:

`this_body.transform.rotation *= Quaternion.FromToRotation(this_body.transform.up,gravity_up);`

And when I am on certain parts of the sphere planet it starts flipping out everywhere, like in [this](https://youtu.be/SFvz1WSs07U) video, and I don't know how to remedy this, although maybe the gravity implementation could be the problem, or the character controller, although I think using relative force should not mess with it.

Gravity Implementation:

```
float distance = direction.magnitude;
float forceMagnitude = G * (obj.GetComponent<MultiAttractor>().rb.mass * rb.mass) / Mathf.Pow(distance, 2);
Vector3 force = direction.normalized * forceMagnitude;
rb.AddForce(force);
```

My character controller script is a bit long so I don't think I should bore you with it, although if needed I could provide it.

Comment: I did not dig much into your problem but you are manipulating the rotation directly in the code with `Quaternion.FromToRotation` and also with physics. I think you need to stick to one of the two, because using both might lead to unexpected behaviours. If you introduce a "raw" rotation modification, the physics engine deals with it.

Comment: Thanks! Had no idea this was a thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is for anyone who is having issues with using [Quaternion.FromToRotation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.FromToRotation.html) with a rigid body character controller:

> I did not dig much into your problem but you are manipulating the rotation directly in the code with Quaternion.FromToRotation and also with physics. I think you need to stick to one of the two, because using both might lead to unexpected behaviours. If you introduce a "raw" rotation modification, the physics engine deals with it. – rustyBucketBay

Basically just use physics rotation like [Rigidbody.rotation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-rotation.html) for rotating things like [Transform.Rotate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html) or if you want to rotate physics objects like you are adding force, but instead of moving things it rotates things, then use [Rigidbody.AddTorque](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddTorque.html), or just don't use any physics rotations with other types of rotation as it can cause problems, as stated by rustyBucketBay